# How to traverse all .txt files in folder?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the code to read only one txt file from the folder, but actually, I need to traverse all of them. And run the same steps for each file and output result. Since I have 6800 files, which means I cannot combine all of them in one data frame.

```
data = 
 pd.read_table("C:path/000007.txt",header=None,delim_whitespace=True)
print(data)


data=data.sort_values(by=4).reset_index(drop = True)

data = data.loc[:,[4,5,6,7]]   #data before process
print(data)

data['hcd'] = data[6] * 0.5 - data[4] * 0.5 + data[4]

data_1 = data[['hcd','vcd','x','y']]  #midpoint and x,y for two points
#print (data_1)

data['hcd2'] = data['hcd']**2
data['vcd2'] = data['vcd']**2

data['x2'] = data['x']**2
data['y2'] = data['y']**2
```

and so on.....

I have the result as:

```
 dis    para result
0  248.87   67.70      1
1  218.96  101.64      1
1    2
Name: result, dtype: int64
```

But this is only one txt result, I want to have all file's result and save in one new txt file like this(also delete the Name: result, dtype: int64):

```
                                         #1(numbers of 1) #0(numbers of 0)
filename1(for example: 000001.txt):      2                 5
filename1(for example: 000001.txt):      6                 7
 ...... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to list the matching files:

```
import glob

# Get all txt files in the directory:
paths = glob.glob('/my/path/*.txt')

for path in paths:
    # Do something with the path
    processPath(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at using os.walk to get all the files and directories. It is also handy as it can traverse subfolders as well:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm